# fs.readFileSync ReferenceError: fileContents is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to read files recursively from directory and trying following code.

```
readDirFiles.list('/dir/subDir/', 'utf8', function (err, filenames) {
      if (err) return console.dir(err);
      //filenames haslist of all files and dirs in '/dir/subDir/'

      if(filenames){
        filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
          //filename is full path of file and array also contains sub directory paths

          try {
            console.log('Opening file '+  filename);
            fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
            console.log(md5(fileContents));
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

        }, this);
      }
    });
```

in `filenames` I have list of all files and directories from which I want to read only files and skip directories. When I am trying to read file using `fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')` it is giving me two erros 
1. `{ [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] errno: -21, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }` this one is ok as it is trying to read directory and not file.
2.`[ReferenceError: fileContents is not defined]` Dont know why this error is coming as I am passing correct file path wit correct extension.

Comment: `utf8` is not an extension rather its the encoding system.What type of files you have in the directory?

Comment: I have .js files in directory. My issue is solved. problem was I have mentioned 'use strict' at top of my file and did not declare 'fileContents' properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script probably has `'use strict'` at the top, and since you're not declaring `fileContents` properly, you're getting a reference error.

To fix, use a proper variable declaration:

```
let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I have voted your answer but due to my less reputation it will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Before reading a file, you should check if the path is directory or filepath.

use [fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) to check if it is a directory and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the read of directory failed because it's not a file, your fileContents variable is undefined and md5 fails with `[ReferenceError: fileContents is not defined]`. You should use the above proposed check using [fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)

Comment: Thanks for reply.  fs.statSync(path).isDirectory() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fs.readFileSync()` requires a full path to the file, not just the name. `filenames` returned by `list` is just a list of filenames, not full path.
2. `fileContents` in your example is not defined as noted by the error.
3. To check if `filename` is a file, you need to first use `fs.stat()`.

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');

   const dir = '/dir/subDir/';

   fs.readdir(dir, function (err, filenames) {
       if (err) {
           return console.dir(err);
       }

       // `filenames` haslist of all file names only.
       Promise.all(filenames.map(filename => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           const filePath = path.join(dir, filename);

           console.log('Opening file '+  filePath);

           fs.stat(filePath, (err, stats) => {
               if (err) {
                   return reject(err);
               }

               if (stats.isFile()) {
                   const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

                   console.log(md5(fileContents));
               }

               resolve();
           });
       })));
   });
   ```